# How do I install Tomee 1.6 on amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-tomee

How do I install Tomee 1.6 on amazon EC2?

I can install tomcat7 by using the command

```
sudo yum install tomcat7-webapps tomcat7-docs-webapp tomcat7-admin-webapps
```

What is the command for install tomee? I don't see it listed in the list of packages.

Answer (score 0):

just download the zip and extract it somewhere.

there is not yet packages in distro (a deb will be soon available btw).

then you can reuse tomcat tools to make it a service if needed.

Comment: When you install tomcat7 using the yum, it distributes the tomcat file/directories to various places. It is not a simple extract of the tomcat7 distribution zip file. If I unzip the tomee distribution file, all file/directories will be in one place. Will this be an issue?